# Get ONLY single digit fom string containing single or double digits using MySql REGEX

Tags: mysql, regex

Lets say I have these string records in a db `"15|26|8"` and `"156|6|24"`. I need a myslq RegEx statement that can find me `6` and **NOT** `26` or `15` and **NOT** `156`. Is this possible with Sql Regex?

Example (regular `LIKE`): `SELECT * FROM db where field LIKE "%6%"`
This statement gets me both records **(NOT what I want)**

Using `IN`only works if my number `6` is the first instance ie `"6|9|24"`

Using `field REGEXP '6'` gives the same result as `field LIKE "%6%"`

New to Regex so following this guide https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html is a bit tough. Any ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: What determines which value is returned? Must the input value be enclosed either by pipes and/or the end/beginning of the string? It is also a bit of a red flag that your data field is not atomic/ contains more than a single value.

Comment: Andy asks some good questions. Here's a hint to get you, or a potential answerer, started: `\d` represents a digit in regex, and `\D` represents a non-digit. `|` represents an "or" (you would need to escape a | to use it literally, as in `\|`), and `^` represents the beginning of a line and `$` as the end. You could write a regex along the lines of "find one digit (`\d`) surround by either a non-digit (`\D`), or (`|`) a line start/end (`^` and `$`)". It might look like this:  __`(\D|^)(\d)(\D|$)`__

Comment: @AndyG I agree. In an ideal world i think a parent child relationship would work better as there are times when the field is single value and times when they are not. But, changing around the tables is not an option at the moment.

Comment: @RToyo Ahh, I see. That is helpful thank you. I'll play around with it.

Comment: @RToyo So the statement would look like: Select * FROM db where field REGEXP (\D|^)(\d{6})(\D|$)?

Comment: @StevenSerrano Something along those lines, yes. However, `\d{6}` will match "six digits"; the curly brackets (`{` and `}`) signify "how many to match". If you want a single digit, you could use `\d{1}`, but this is implied when you only use `\d`. Unfortunately my use of regex in MySQL is rusty, as I use a different RDBMS in my day-to-day, so I'm not sure if that is the exact syntax to use for querying. You can use a regex sandbox/fiddle, such as [regexr](https://regexr.com/), to test out your regular expressions.

Comment: Are you looking for "any single digit number"?  Or for specifically "the number 6"?

Answer (score 0):

```
FIND_IN_SET('6', REPLACE(col, '|', ','))
```

Using your examples:

```
mysql> SELECT FIND_IN_SET('6', REPLACE("15|26|8", '|', ','));
+------------------------------------------------+
| FIND_IN_SET('6', REPLACE("15|26|8", '|', ',')) |
+------------------------------------------------+
|                                              0 |
+------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT FIND_IN_SET('6', REPLACE("156|6|24", '|', ','));
+-------------------------------------------------+
| FIND_IN_SET('6', REPLACE("156|6|24", '|', ',')) |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|                                               2 |
+-------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

See also `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`